# Autoscale celery workers having complex Celery Chains

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, autoscaling

I'm trying to draft out how autoscaling would work with celery having complex chain based workflows.

Current Flow:

30 CSVs are downloaded (every 6 hours) then a celery group is created to monitor the individual threads where each CSV is being pre-processed and saved on /tmp/folder/

After all the tasks are successful and the celery group returns True, the /tmp/folder/ is zipped and stored on S3 and other systems are notified through an API call.

**Challenge faced**:

We have loads of pending tasks around 40-50 tasks, and making the overall process really slow.

**Proposed Solution**:

Autoscale i.e add more worker servers based on number of pending tasks.

Is this approach possible for the workflow that I have ? Or is there is possibility of having a vertical scaling solution ? What is the best way to tackle this problem ?

```
@app.task
def process_csv(path_of_csv):
    # preprocessing the csv and storing in /tmp/folder/
    return True
```

```
res = group(process_csv.s(path) for path in all_paths)()
with allow_join_result():
     print(res.get())
     if 'False' not in res.get():
         # Time to store to S3
```

**Environment Info**

```
aiodns==2.0.0
aiohttp==3.5.4
amqp==2.5.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.1.0
Babel==2.7.0
billiard==3.5.0.5
boto3==1.9.197
botocore==1.12.197
celery==4.1.1
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
ddtrace==0.31.0
Django==2.2.3
django-enumfields==1.0.0
django-extensions==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.10.1
docutils==0.14
flower==0.9.3
gevent==1.4.0
greenlet==0.4.15
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
idna-ssl==1.1.0
jmespath==0.9.4
kombu==4.6.3
multidict==4.5.2
psutil==5.6.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
pycares==3.0.0
pycparser==2.19
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
redis==3.3.0
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
six==1.12.0
slackclient==2.0.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
tornado==5.1.1
typing==3.7.4
typing-extensions==3.7.4
urllib3==1.25.3
vine==1.3.0
websocket==0.2.1
websocket-client==0.56.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
yarl==1.3.0
```

I'm using RabbitMQ broker and Redis as Backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this involves 4 steps

1. Download CSV
2. Process CSV
3. Zip /tmp/folder
4. Upload to cloud (S3)

Bottle neck is in step-2.

You have mentioned 40-50 tasks pending, assuming you are processing one file per task, this should be equal or less than 30 (number of CSV files).
Why are there 40-50 tasks?

This is unclear to me. Can you explain why tasks are more than number of files being pre-processed?

Before exploring auto scaling, can you explore `--concurrency`, set it to 30 or more and try to find if it's still the problem, it will help to find the bottle neck.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

BTW, saw one more thread, **autoscaling in celery 4.0 seems to be broken** (yours is `celery==4.1.1`), not sure. Check thread:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4003

Comment: There are 40-50 pending tasks as there are 10 sources of download_csv buckets. 
And what I'm looking for autoscaling i.e either increasing the instance type of the server to something higher (Horizontal) or launching new servers to process jobs. 

so I'm unaffected by --autoscale parameter. Plus my servers are running at 100% CPU hence increasing the concurrency would affect the performance.